# How to access get accessors from soda within cucumber js

Tags: cucumber

I am new to cucumber js and am attempting to write a test scenario which will compare the number of actual rows in a table with a known count.

I am using the getXpathCount function but wondered how i can actually read the response from the method call, here is what i have already:

```
determineNumRows: function (callback) {
var self = this;
self.browser
    .chain
    .getXpathCount("//div[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr")
    .setTimeout(1000)
    .end(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            callback.fail(err);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

from reading up on the getXpathCount function it looks like this should return the number of nodes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work (untested):

```
determineNumRows: function (callback) {
var self = this;
var trCount = 0;
self.browser
    .chain
    .getXpathCount("//div[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr", function (count) { 
        trCount = count; 
    })
    .setTimeout(1000)
    .end(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            callback.fail(err);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i have tried this however, when i display the value of trCount it is always 0, it is not setting this variable as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Where to you output the trCount? Be careful to use it within the `end()` callback, not after it as it's asynchronous code you're dealing with.

Comment: Actually that worked my mistake, now that i can get the value returned, is there a way of getting this without the chaining, i tried this without success:
var test = self.browser.getXpathCount(......

Comment: Remember, it's all asynchronous. Something like this should do it: `self.browser.getXpathCount("//xx", function (err, result) { ...`